# UWP - AppShell.xmal - MUXC:NavigationViewItem - List of available Icons (not costume made)

Tags: uwp-xaml, uwp-navigation

Currently, I am working on a solution Universal Windows (C#/xaml), where the namespace Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls is used.

```
            <MUXC:NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <MUXC:NavigationViewItem
                x:Name="ExpensesRecordsMenuItem"
                Content="{x:Bind Label}" 
                ToolTipService.ToolTip="{x:Bind Label`}"
                Icon="ContactInfo"/>
            <MUXC:NavigationViewItem
                x:Name="IncomeRecordsMenuItem"
                Content="{x:Bind Label1}" 
                ToolTipService.ToolTip="{x:Bind Label1}"
                Icon="Shop"/>
        </MUXC:NavigationView.MenuItems>
```

As one can see, the Icon takes a string value which is expected by NavigationViewItem and return an Icon object on the GUI, as part of the navigation view. Hence, no costume icon I had to add to the solution/project.

I have failed to find a reference to all possible list of Icons on-line, so, I could use Windows natural assets, instead of creating new icons all the time.

**Is there any chance anyone here has found that list?**

Thank you in advance.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find the complete list of icon names from [Symbol enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbol?view=winrt-19041) then use it like the following.

```
<NavigationViewItem x:Name="ExpensesRecordsMenuItem" Content="item1" Icon="CalendarDay"/>
```

If you would like to use a glyph from the [Segoe MDL2 Assets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font) font that is not included in the Symbol enumeration, then use a [FontIcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.fonticon?view=winrt-19041) like following.

```
      <NavigationView>
            <NavigationView.MenuItems>
                <NavigationViewItem x:Name="ExpensesRecordsMenuItem" Content="item1">
                    <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                        <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE790;"/>
                    </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                </NavigationViewItem>
            </NavigationView.MenuItems>
        </NavigationView>
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much AryaDing.

Comment: Your code snipped is much better then original one here `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationviewitem.icon?view=winrt-20348`